# Automatically mouting partitions at startup

Tags: mount, startup, partitioning, mountpoint

Other than my OS partition, I have two other partitions on my drive. At startup, one of them is automatically loaded while the other one is not. How to change the settings so that none of them is automatically loaded at startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `/etc/fstab` with `sudo -e /etc/fstab` and comment `#` line containing partition you don't want. In second column you have mountpoints. Don't touch root partition `/`